# Convert sequence of JSON lines (JSONL) to JSON array

Tags: json, bash, jq, jsonlines

I have a file where each line is a JSON object. I'd like to convert the file to a JSON array.

The file looks something like this:

```
{"address":"email1@foo.bar.com", "topic":"Some topic."}
{"address":"email2@foo.bar.com", "topic":"Another topic."}
{"address":"email3@foo.bar.com", "topic":"Yet another topic."}
```

I'm using bash and jq.

I tried

```
jq --slurp --raw-input 'split("\n")[:-1]' my_file
```

But that just treats each line as a string creating a JSON array of strings.

```
[
  "{\"address\":\"email1@foo.bar.com\", \"topic\":\"Some topic.\"}",
  "{\"address\":\"email2@foo.bar.com\", \"topic\":\"Another topic.\"}",
  "{\"address\":\"email3@foo.bar.com\", \"topic\":\"Yet another topic.\"}"
]
```

I'd like to have:

```
[
  {"address":"email1@foo.bar.com", "topic":"Some topic."},
  {"address":"email2@foo.bar.com", "topic":"Another topic."},
  {"address":"email3@foo.bar.com", "topic":"Yet another topic."}
]
```

Comment: How about just `jq --slurp < my_file`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
jq -n '[inputs]' <in.jsonl >out.json
```

...or, as [suggested by @borrible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637859/convert-sequence-of-json-objects-to-json-array#comment107279792_60637859):

```
jq --slurp . <in.jsonl >out.json
```

Answer (score 3):

For the task at hand, using jq's "slurp" option or `[inputs]` entails a potentially huge waste of resources.

A trivial but efficient solution can be implemented in awk as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "[";} NF==0{next;} n=="" {print;n++;next;} {print ","; print;} END {print "]"}'
```

An equivalent efficient solution in jq is possible using `foreach` and `inputs`, and is left as an exercise.